# CustomPainter : triggering a repaint from hitTest method

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to trigger a repaint depending on a value resulting from a hitTest?

In the following code sample I want to draw a circle wherever a hit has been detected.

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
    Offset _hitPosition = Offset.zero;

    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
        canvas.drawCircle(_hitPosition, 20, Paint());
    }

    @override
    bool? hitTest(Offset position){
        _hitPosition = position;
        // Need to trigger a repaint here
    }
}
```

The most obvious way would be to use a Listenable in a constructor :

```
Listenable _hitPosition;
MyCustomPainter(this._hitPosition) : super(repaint: _hitPosition);
```

But I was wondering is there was a way to do it "from inside";

I'm surprised there isn't a method `this.repaint()` but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more consideration I came to the conclusion that this attempt is vain.

The myCustomPainter instance will be discarded at each rebuild thus  can not maintain internal state. Even if there was a method like `this.repaint()` to force a repaint, the value of _hitPosition could be reset to its default value anytime.